# Serializable filter on any object

Tags: c#, json

I need a way to define a filter for an unknown type. The filter should be able to check an incoming JSON object against that filter. The filter should be JSON-serializable as well.

For example a filter that defines:

- The object should have a property Prop1 with value Val1
- It should have a property Prop2 that has an object as value, with SubProp1 equal to Val2
- It should have a Prop3 that contains one of these values: [1, 2, 3]

Does something like this already exist, or will I need to implement this from scratch?

Comment: Just realized I may get far with JSON schema. Maybe not 100% what I need, but it's a start.

Comment: Can you show an example how the filter string would look like?

Comment: Well, the exact syntax is yet to be defined. I'm looking for some library that does something like this.

An example in words:
An object with a property Links which contains objects which have a property ID. The value of this ID property should be an item of this list: [1, 2, 42, 89, 16].

This is of course only a very small example. In reality, the filter will contain many properties, which hold on its own complex types, with many properties.

Comment: You may want to use a [JSON Schema](https://json-schema.org/).  See the tag [tag:jsonschema].  Newtonsoft has [schema support](https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema) as a paid extra.

Answer (score 1):

If your json serialiser is Json.NET then a validate method that uses `JObject` should do the job (official examples [here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJson.htm)).

For example:

```
bool Validate(string json) 
{
    JObject rss = JObject.Parse(json);
    if(((string)rss["Prop1"]) != "Val1" ) return false;
    ...
```

For the new .NET Core/5 `System.Text.Json` serialiser, a similar solution could be build with `JsonDocument.Parse`. An example is shown in [Try the new System.Text.Json APIs](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/try-the-new-system-text-json-apis/).

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer. The difficult part is that the filter should be serialized as well. Both the JSON and the filter (serialized as JSON) are input of my program.